# How to block unwanted sites from opening?

Tags: safari, websites

How do you block websites on Safari?

Comment: aer you looking to block just a single site, or a whole bunch of sites?  The solution could be different depending on your situation.

Comment: Why was the question downvoted - I could see a user wanting to use this to deal with popups/popunders - which without some of the neat add ons to other browsers is a problem in safari.

Answer (score 5):

You can add an entry to your `/etc/hosts` file. For each site you want to block, add a line at the bottom, in the form:

`127.0.0.1 site-to-block.com`